# How to score documents higher based on nested type size in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Mapping in ES:

```
"contributors" : {
  "type" : "nested",
  "properties" : {
    "title" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "autocomplete" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "nGram_analyzer"
        },
        "raw" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "normalizer" : "lowercase_normalizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some documents have multiple contributors but I want to score higher those documents with only one and matching contributor. So documents with multiple contributors would score lower even if the contributor is matching.

Is there any other way than add the size in index or flatten the contributor names to a single string?